# Can any mobile automation tool work on current device session?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, monkeyrunner

I am working on an android app, which has two user flows. Let's call them flow A and B !! Now, flow B is dependent on flow A, means flow B can only be performed after flow A. And, if user performs flow A and then kills the app, he/she won't be able to perform flow B (unless he/she performs flow A again)

What my requirement is - user manually perform flow A, then plugs in the device to the usb port and then my automation script should perform flow B in the same  or current device session.

Most of mobile automation tools like Appium runs their own sessions on their servers, so to perform flow A manually and then to perform flow B automatically seems infeasible in this case.

So, is there any other mobile automation tool or any way through which I can achieve above scenario ?? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can start first appium session then in your script put wait like expected condition occurs so mean while you can perform your flow A manually and after that on current appium session your flow B can be performed with appium.
This is not the best solution but this might can work for you.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for answering. But, I don't wanna perform flow A at all. We have a test scenario where flow A is done only once and then check validations on flow B. So, I just wanna check validations on flow B, without performing flow A.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in achieving what you describe (are flow A and B Activities?) using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).

You can start flow A, manually, and then start the test case for flow B (which can be generated using [culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI)).

Comment: Sure, I will check it out and get back. Thanks